# Jsplumb connectors not displaying

Tags: jsplumb, html2canvas

When using 
.setRenderMode(jsPlumb.CANVAS); --> taking pdf from chrome, connection are not displayed(but in html page showing) -- check the image (2nd image- pdf generated by chrome, 1st image- html page)

similarly while using html2canvas conversion the connection are not displaying , other elements working fine. - check image below((2nd -  pdf generated by chrome, 1st image-html page))

but with svg - working fine in chrome pdf but not in html2canvs[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/391 - add your comment to html2canvas